# Right or wrong? Limit of sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{a_n\}$ a sequence such that $a_n\ge0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. We suppose that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0.
\end{equation}
I would like to show that $a_n=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then from the definition of limit for all $\epsilon>0$ $\exists n_0>0$ such that
\begin{equation}
0\le a_n<\epsilon\quad\text{for all}\;n>n_0>0
\end{equation}
can I conclude by saying that $a_n=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is really not clear!

Comment: What are you trying to prove here? What exactly are your assumptions?

Comment: I don't get your last "therefore". Take $\epsilon=10^{-18}$. What stops $a_{n_0(\epsilon)-1}$ from being $1715$?

Comment: No, you certainly cannot conclude that $a_n = 0$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$.  In fact it might be that every single $a_n \gt 0$, e.g. $a_n = 1/n$, yet $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = 0$.  At best you are confusing the order of quantification in your reasoning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you write is neither right nor wrong, since you don't tell us what $n_0$ is. But, whatever you may add about about $n_0$ will turn your statment into a false one (assuming that it turns it into a meaningful statement). For instance, $\lim_{n\in\mathbb N}\frac1n=0$, but it is not true that $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):\frac1n=0$.

Answer (score 2):

$a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ is a sequence such that $a_n > 0$ for all $n$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$, but $a_n$ itself is never zero.

So the statement (as I understand it) is false.

Comment: Thanks for your ansewer, but by hypothesis $a_n\ge0$.

Comment: Oria's example satisfies that.  You have not said what values $a_n$ may take.  If real, as most seemed to have assumed, then Oria's example disproves your claim. However, if $a_n$ are integers then it is true.

Answer (score 1):

If $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ then for every $\epsilon>0$ an integer $n_{\epsilon}$ exists such that $n> n_{\epsilon}$ implies that $a_n<\epsilon$.

Note that $n_{\epsilon}$ **depends** on $\epsilon$.